# crontab -e: crontabs: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, debian, cron, crontab

I am trying to set up a cron job in my user crontab on a debian 11 image on a VPS.

But I have issues and cannot open crontab:

```
flo@debian-2gb:~$ crontab -e
crontabs: No such file or directory
flo@debian-2gb:~$ crontab -l
crontabs: No such file or directory
flo@debian-2gb:~$ sudo crontab -l
crontabs: No such file or directory
crontabs: mkdir: Operation not permitted
flo@debian-2gb:$ file /usr/bin/crontab
/usr/bin/crontab: setgid ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=e7fb2e8014f70bd0f4222e0c69566c721a323513, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

I tried `echo "export EDITOR=nano" >> ~/.bashrc` and sourced it, since it was not set, but it did not help.

I tried to reinstall cron:

```
flo@debian-2gb:~$ sudo apt-get reinstall cron
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
Need to get 99.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 cron amd64 3.0pl1-137 [99.6 kB]
Fetched 99.6 kB in 0s (3470 kB/s)
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LC_TERMINAL = "iTerm2",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 59567 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cron_3.0pl1-137_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cron (3.0pl1-137) over (3.0pl1-137) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/cron_3.0pl1-137_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/etc/cron.d/.placeholder.dpkg-new' (while processing './etc/cron.d/.placeholder'): Operation not permitted
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/cron_3.0pl1-137_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have debian running on another vps and there I have no issues editing my crontab, same locale on both systems.

I have absolutely no clue what the problem is, and all solutions I have found so far did not help. How can I debug this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
root@debian-2gb:/# ls -ld /var/spool/cron/crontabs/
ls: cannot access '/var/spool/cron/crontabs/': No such file or directory
```

**EDIT 2**

```
ls -al /var/spool/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Nov 23 10:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 Nov 23 10:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 18 01:54 cron
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    7 Nov 23 10:33 mail -> ../mail
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Feb 17  2021 rsyslog
```

```
cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Comment: Add output of `ls -ld /var/spool/cron/crontabs/` to question

Comment: I have added the output...

Comment: Do /var/spool and /var/spool/cron exist?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: You are on Debian 11 not 10. Right?

Comment: @user10489  Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye).

Comment: @GAD3R yes... Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Comment: @GordonDavisson yes, these exist, I added the info in EDIT 2.